# R Proteomics: issues with input file "ExpressionSet" : Processing information: msmsTest package

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genome, protein-database

## Updated Question:

I want to use the msmsTest package for statistics of my proteomics data (which is spectral counts type).

However, I have a message error when importing the file with the commands:

```
e <- pp.msms.data(myStackoverflowexample)
Error in MSnbase:::logging(msnset, "Applied pp.msms.data preprocessing") : 
  no slot of name "processingData" for this object of class "ExpressionSet".
```

I think that my problem comes from the previous step when I try to generate the file in the appropriate format which should be a ExpressionSet file. For this I have tried to follow step by step the ExpressionSetIntroduction manual, it seems OK to me, but I get the error whenever I use the command "e <- pp.msms.data(myStackoverflowexample)" with the msmsTest package.

Please help me I am stuck since weeks and it is probably a very stupid thing i am missing.

You can get the example datasets (raw data and phenodata) here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9ts4k5qrnyem6d/rawdata.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oy6n6y5hfq30ee/pdata.txt?dl=0

Below is the code that allows me to build the ExpressionSet file from scratch :

```
library(limma)
library(MSnbase)
library(msmsEDA)
library(msmsTests)
library(edgeR)


# creation of the file "assay data" in the correct format :

dataDirectory<- setwd(".../msmsTest-essai - stkvflw")
exprsFile <- file.path(dataDirectory, "rawdata.txt")
exprs <- as.matrix(read.table(exprsFile, header=TRUE,     sep="\t",row.names=1))

# creation of the phenotypic data file:

pDataFile <- file.path(dataDirectory, "pdata.txt")
pData <- read.table(pDataFile,row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t")  
head(pData)

all(rownames(pData)==colnames(exprs)) # verification that rows and names of both files match

metadata <- data.frame(labelDescription= c("molecule treatment",  
                                           "number of years", 
                                           "tissues from Velpeau Hospital patients", 
                                           "in cm", 
                                           "in kg"), 
                       row.names=c("treat", "age", "tissue", "height", "weight"))

phenoData <- new("AnnotatedDataFrame", data=pData, varMetadata=metadata)

experimentData <- new("MIAME",
                      name="Mickael Jordan",
                      lab="Chicago Bulls",
                      contact="mjordan@lab.not.exist",
                      title="Basket-ball Research Institute",
                      abstract="An example ExpressionSet",
                      url="www.lab.not.exist",
                      other=list(
                        notes="Created from text files"
                      ))

myStackoverflowexample <- ExpressionSet(assayData=exprs,  
                                        phenoData=phenoData,
                                        experimentData=experimentData,
                                        annotation="blablabla")



myStackoverflowexample

ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 8 features, 208 samples 
  element names: exprs 
protocolData: none
phenoData
  sampleNames: A1 A2 ... C64 (208 total)
  varLabels: treat age ... weight (5 total)
  varMetadata: labelDescription
featureData: none
experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'
Annotation: blablabla 

summary(myStackoverflowexample)
 Length         Class          Mode 
        1 ExpressionSet            S4
```

So after this code, I am stuck with the msmsTest package:

```
e <- pp.msms.data(myStackoverflowexample)
Error in MSnbase:::logging(msnset, "Applied pp.msms.data preprocessing") : 
  no slot of name "processingData" for this object of class "ExpressionSet"
```

If we look at the manual example, we see a line with "processing information" that did not appear when typing `myStackoverflowexample`

```
data(msms.dataset) # example given in the manual
msms.dataset

MSnSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 697 features, 14 samples 
  element names: exprs 
protocolData: none
phenoData
  sampleNames: U2.2502.1 U2.2502.2 ... U6.0302.3 (14 total)
  varLabels: treat batch
  varMetadata: labelDescription
featureData: none
experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'
  pubMedIds: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22588121 
Annotation:  
- - - **Processing information** - - -
 MSnbase version: 1.8.0
```

Any clue about this issue and finally be able to process my file with statistical analyses ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

## Initial (and so previous) Question :

I want to try the msmsTest package.

However, when I try the code from the manual with my example dataset, i have the following error message :

```
b<-read.delim("example.data.set.txt")

head(b)

 name condition tissue    LogFC
1         kjhss1   control  brain 7.129283
2          sdth2   control  brain 7.179909
3     sgdhstjh20   control  brain 9.353147
4 jdygfjgdkydg21   control  brain 6.459432
5  shfjdfyjydg22   control  brain 9.372865
6      jdyjkdg23   control  brain 9.541097

str(b)
'data.frame':   4461 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ name     : Factor w/ 1131 levels "dghwg1041","dghwg1086",..: 480 761 787      360 863 385 133 888 563 738 ...
 $ condition: Factor w/ 5 levels "control","treatmentA",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1     1 ...
 $ tissue   : Factor w/ 2 levels "brain","heart": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LogFC    : num  7.13 7.18 9.35 6.46 9.37 ...

e <- pp.msms.data(b)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘exprs’ for signature     ‘"data.frame"’
```

So I am am stuck there and I cannot go further.

I have tried to define my dataset as.data.frame() or as.matrix(), but i get the same error message.

I have read information about the exprs() function in biobase:
"These generic functions access the expression and error measurements of assay data stored in an object derived from the eSet-class."

But it doesn't help me much... I have read some post related to similar exprs() issues for genomic data but it sounds like "gibberish" to me. Apparently, perhaps something 's wrong with eSet-class structure of my data.frame but I don't understand what does this means and how to solve it.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue and how to proceed ?

So many thanks in advance,

Kind regards,

SkyR

Comment: What script are you trying to follow?

Comment: It is the script from the manual of the msmsTest package

Comment: no one ? no clue ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `msmsTests` [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/msmsTests/inst/doc/msmsTests-Vignette.pdf), and the `pp.msms.data` function [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/msmsEDA/versions/1.10.0/topics/pp.msms.data), the function only accepts the following as its argument:

> msnset: A `MSnSet` with spectral counts in the expression matrix.

The vignette's Section 2 (An example LC-MS/MS dataset) shows you an example. You will have to make your data into a class that `pp.msms.data` accepts---this is no simple dataframe nor a matrix.

> This
>   MSnSet
>   object contains a spectral counts (SpC) matrix in the
>   assayData
>   slot, and a factor treatment in the
>   phenoData
>   slot.  (See also the expressionSet
>   vignette by vignette(”ExpressionSetIntroduction”,package=”Biobase”) [10])

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand how to convert my excel/text file into the accepted format for this package.